# issue with creation of matrix: non-conformable arguments

Tags: r, regression

my data is:

```
> ptest
   Obs.Name      S1      L1      P1     S2      L2      P2      S3      L3     P3
1     VESSK -2.6931 -2.5271 -1.2871 3.0777  0.3891 -0.0701  1.9607 -1.6324 0.5746
3     VEASK -2.6931 -2.5271 -1.2871 3.0777  0.3891 -0.0701  0.0744 -1.7333 0.0902
5     VKAAK -2.6931 -2.5271 -1.2871 2.8369  1.4092 -3.1398  0.0744 -1.7333 0.0902
6     VEWAK -2.6931 -2.5271 -1.2871 3.0777  0.3891 -0.0701 -4.7548  3.6521 0.8524
8     VEHAK -2.6931 -2.5271 -1.2871 3.0777  0.3891 -0.0701  2.4064  1.7438 1.1057
10    GEAAK  2.2261 -5.3648  0.3049 3.0777  0.3891 -0.0701  0.0744 -1.7333 0.0902
12    FEAAK -4.9217  1.2977  0.4473 3.0777  0.3891 -0.0701  0.0744 -1.7333 0.0902
20    VAWAK -2.6931 -2.5271 -1.2871 0.0744 -1.7333  0.0902 -4.7548  3.6521 0.8524
27    VEWVK -2.6931 -2.5271 -1.2871 3.0777  0.3891 -0.0701 -4.7548  3.6521 0.8524
28    PGFSP -1.2201  0.8829  2.2253 2.2261 -5.3648  0.3049 -4.9217  1.2977 0.4473
        S4      L4      P4      S5     L5      P5 log.RAI
1   1.9607 -1.6324  0.5746  2.8369 1.4092 -3.1398    0.00
3   1.9607 -1.6324  0.5746  2.8369 1.4092 -3.1398    0.20
5   0.0744 -1.7333  0.0902  2.8369 1.4092 -3.1398    0.11
6   0.0744 -1.7333  0.0902  2.8369 1.4092 -3.1398    2.73
8   0.0744 -1.7333  0.0902  2.8369 1.4092 -3.1398    1.53
10  0.0744 -1.7333  0.0902  2.8369 1.4092 -3.1398   -0.52
12  0.0744 -1.7333  0.0902  2.8369 1.4092 -3.1398    0.30
20  0.0744 -1.7333  0.0902  2.8369 1.4092 -3.1398    1.45
27 -2.6931 -2.5271 -1.2871  2.8369 1.4092 -3.1398    1.71
``28  1.9607 -1.6324  0.5746 -1.2201 0.8829  2.2253    0.90
```

and I did a lr.ridge model:

```
lm.ridge(formula = log.RAI ~ ., data = ptrain[,-1],
+                          lambda = seq(0, 10, len = 21))
```

and I want to create a data set to be able to test the model with the test data. I tried

```
predicciones <- cbind(1, as.matrix(ptest[, -1,-16])) %*% coef(modelo_ridge4)
Error in cbind(1, as.matrix(ptest[, -1, -16])) %*% coef(modelo_ridge4) : 
  non-conformable arguments
```

and

```
predic<-as.matrix(cbind(const=1,ptrain[,-1])) %*% coef(modelo_ridge4)
Error in as.matrix(cbind(const = 1, ptrain[, -1])) %*% coef(modelo_ridge4) : 
  non-conformable arguments
```

both give the same error that there are non conformable arguments, I also tried to do the model with a given lambda and with no range, and the error is the same

the ptest data to build the model is:

```
> ptrain
   Obs.Name      S1      L1      P1      S2      L2      P2      S3      L3
22    VWAAK -2.6931 -2.5271 -1.2871 -4.7548  3.6521  0.8524  0.0744 -1.7333
18    AAWAA  0.0744 -1.7333  0.0902  0.0744 -1.7333  0.0902 -4.7548  3.6521
13    VEGGK -2.6931 -2.5271 -1.2871  3.0777  0.3891 -0.0701  2.2261 -5.3648
25    VKWAP -2.6931 -2.5271 -1.2871  2.8369  1.4092 -3.1398 -4.7548  3.6521
24    EKWAP  3.0777  0.3891 -0.0701  2.8369  1.4092 -3.1398 -4.7548  3.6521
16    AAAAA  0.0744 -1.7333  0.0902  0.0744 -1.7333  0.0902  0.0744 -1.7333
17    AAYAA  0.0744 -1.7333  0.0902  0.0744 -1.7333  0.0902 -1.3944  2.3230
4     VEAAK -2.6931 -2.5271 -1.2871  3.0777  0.3891 -0.0701  0.0744 -1.7333
15    VELAK -2.6931 -2.5271 -1.2871  3.0777  0.3891 -0.0701 -4.1921 -1.0285
11    LEAAK -4.1921 -1.0285 -0.9801  3.0777  0.3891 -0.0701  0.0744 -1.7333
29    FSPFR -4.9217  1.2977  0.4473  1.9607 -1.6324  0.5746 -1.2201  0.8829
30    RYLPT  2.8827  2.5215 -3.4435 -1.3944  2.3230  0.0139 -4.1921 -1.0285
9     VAAAK -2.6931 -2.5271 -1.2871  0.0744 -1.7333  0.0902  0.0744 -1.7333
2     VESAK -2.6931 -2.5271 -1.2871  3.0777  0.3891 -0.0701  1.9607 -1.6324
21    VKWAA -2.6931 -2.5271 -1.2871  2.8369  1.4092 -3.1398 -4.7548  3.6521
19    VAWAA -2.6931 -2.5271 -1.2871  0.0744 -1.7333  0.0902 -4.7548  3.6521
26    RKWAP  2.8827  2.5215 -3.4435  2.8369  1.4092 -3.1398 -4.7548  3.6521
23    VAAWK -2.6931 -2.5271 -1.2871  0.0744 -1.7333  0.0902  0.0744 -1.7333
7     VEAAP -2.6931 -2.5271 -1.2871  3.0777  0.3891 -0.0701  0.0744 -1.7333
14    VEFAK -2.6931 -2.5271 -1.2871  3.0777  0.3891 -0.0701 -4.9217  1.2977
        P3      S4      L4     P4      S5      L5      P5 log.RAI
22  0.0902  0.0744 -1.7333 0.0902  2.8369  1.4092 -3.1398    0.04
18  0.8524  0.0744 -1.7333 0.0902  0.0744 -1.7333  0.0902    0.75
13  0.3049  2.2261 -5.3648 0.3049  2.8369  1.4092 -3.1398   -1.00
25  0.8524  0.0744 -1.7333 0.0902 -1.2201  0.8829  2.2253    2.35
24  0.8524  0.0744 -1.7333 0.0902 -1.2201  0.8829  2.2253    1.30
16  0.0902  0.0744 -1.7333 0.0902  0.0744 -1.7333  0.0902   -0.10
17  0.0139  0.0744 -1.7333 0.0902  0.0744 -1.7333  0.0902    0.46
4   0.0902  0.0744 -1.7333 0.0902  2.8369  1.4092 -3.1398    0.51
15 -0.9801  0.0744 -1.7333 0.0902  2.8369  1.4092 -3.1398    0.59
11  0.0902  0.0744 -1.7333 0.0902  2.8369  1.4092 -3.1398    0.40
29  2.2253 -4.9217  1.2977 0.4473  2.8827  2.5215 -3.4435    0.64
30 -0.9801 -1.2201  0.8829 2.2253  0.9243 -2.0921 -1.3996    0.40
9   0.0902  0.0744 -1.7333 0.0902  2.8369  1.4092 -3.1398   -0.10
2   0.5746  0.0744 -1.7333 0.0902  2.8369  1.4092 -3.1398    0.28
21  0.8524  0.0744 -1.7333 0.0902  0.0744 -1.7333  0.0902    1.71
19  0.8524  0.0744 -1.7333 0.0902  0.0744 -1.7333  0.0902    1.43
26  0.8524  0.0744 -1.7333 0.0902 -1.2201  0.8829  2.2253    1.98
23  0.0902 -4.7548  3.6521 0.8524  2.8369  1.4092 -3.1398    0.23
7   0.0902  0.0744 -1.7333 0.0902 -1.2201  0.8829  2.2253    0.18
14  0.4473  0.0744 -1.7333 0.0902  2.8369  1.4092 -3.1398    1.57
```

Anyone could helping finding the issue and how to fix it? I do not totally understand what the nonconformable arguments

thanks and kind regards

Comment: My guess is that for `%*%` you need an m x n matrix times an n x p matrix, and the dimensions of your two matrices probably don't meet that. For `ptest` did you want to remove the first and last columns? Would that be `ptest[, c(-1,-17)])` unless I miscounted? In addition, would try transposing the other matrix `t(coef(modelo_ridge4))` from `lm.ridge`. If this is way off I will delete this comment.

Comment: Reducing the data to the absolute minimum that should run without error can often aid in troubleshooting. My suggestion is to create a test data set with the absolute minimum number of columns and rows that should work correctly - and if it does work correctly, increase the data set until the problem occurs.